# Como fazer sql para um campo de uma tabela que não seja primário se tornar estrangeira em outra tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE PESSOA
(   
    ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    CPF VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    RG VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    DATA_NASCIMENTO DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

CREATE TABLE CADASTRO
(
    ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RA INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(128),
    NOTA_TEORICA NUMERIC(10,2),
    NOTA_LAB NUMERIC(10,2),
    MEDIA NUMERIC(10,5),
    FK_CPF INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
```

Preciso que o campo CPF da tabela PESSOA seja chave estrangeira em FK_CPF da tabela CADASTRO

Comment: Por curiosidade, por que não usa o ID como FK? Tem certeza que fez a modelagem corretamente? Se o CPF não é PK nem UK, não será possível cadastrar duas pessoas com o mesmo CPF?

Comment: Neste caso específico eu preciso do CPF, mas ele também poderia ser UK, nem pensei nisso ... como ficaria o sql então para que ele seja UK na tabela PESSOA e que seja referenciado em FK_CPF ?

Comment: CPF é varchar ou integer?

Comment: cpf é um varchar

Answer (score 2):

No script que cria a tabela cadastro você deve alterar a coluna cpf da tabela de pessoa para unique da seguinte forma:

```
CPF VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL e na tabela de cadastro 

FK_CPF VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
```

Isso permitirá que em outras tabelas tenha uma fk referenciando está coluna porque o UNIQUE garantirá que só poderá existir um registro único de cpf para cada linha da tabela PESSOA e adicionar a linha para FK

```
FOREIGN KEY FK_KEY_CPF (FK_CPF) REFERENCES PESSOA(CPF)
```

como especificado abaixo

```
 CREATE TABLE PESSOA
(   
    ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    CPF VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    RG VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    DATA_NASCIMENTO DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    UNIQUE(CPF)
)

CREATE TABLE CADASTRO
(
    ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RA INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(128),
    NOTA_TEORICA NUMERIC(10,2),
    NOTA_LAB NUMERIC(10,2),
    MEDIA NUMERIC(10,5),
    FK_CPF VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),

    FOREIGN KEY FK_KEY_CPF (FK_CPF) REFERENCES PESSOA(CPF)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer com que CPF, seja uma `UniqueKey`.

Isso pra facilitar, porque, na verdade, só é necessário que a coluna esteja indexada.

Fonte [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Additionally, MySQL requires that the referenced columns be indexed for performance reasons.

Exemplo com `UniqueKey`:

```
CREATE TABLE PESSOA
(   
    ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
    CPF VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    RG VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    DATA_NASCIMENTO DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE(CPF)
)
```

Depois, é só referenciar normalmente.

```
CREATE TABLE CADASTRO
(
    ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RA INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(128),
    NOTA_TEORICA NUMERIC(10,2),
    NOTA_LAB NUMERIC(10,2),
    MEDIA NUMERIC(10,5),
    FK_CPF VARCHAR UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FK_CPF) REFERENCES PESSOA(CPF)
)
```